# Make a street pattern for regex using C#

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I'm trying to check validation of string that should describe a street's name.

The template is: number of words start with capital letter, and number with 1 through 4 digits.

Example: `Name Of Street 101`

I tried this:

```
Regex stRegex = new Regex(@"^[A-Z][a-z]+ [1-9]+$");
```

But it seems to not working.

What is the pattern should be to make it work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only check for a single word, and you do not allow zeros in the number. Maybe something more like this?

```
@"^(?:[A-Z][a-z]+ )+[1-9][0-9]{0,3}$"
```

However your template is a bit restrictive, I think. What about `O'Sullivan Street`? And you might also want to allow multiple spaces (by adding another `+` right after the space).

Comment: Thanks you very much! it works. i just have a question: what "?:" means?

Comment: @user1798362 it is just an optimization. If you leave it out, the parentheses create a capturing group which you don't need (the stuff that is matched by a capturing group can be accessed separately later on). But capturing is expensive, which is why it is generally good practice to make all groups, whose submatches you don't need, non-capturing.

Comment: Thank you. last question, the `{0,3}` sets the range for digits?

Comment: @user1798362 it repeats the previous character (an arbitrary digit) 0 to 3 times (your `+` there would allow arbitrarily many). note that each repetition can be a different digit. it is equivalent to `[0-9]?[0-9]?[0-9]?`. I suggest you read through [this very comprehensive tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html).

Comment: I got it. thanks you again! And I'll give you the best answer in two minutes. (for some reason i am unable to do it now)

Comment: @user1798362 yes, you cannot accept an answer within the first 15 minutes after asking a question.